# Confused about instance initialization

Tags: java

I have a class, such as:

```
public class Test {

    private static Thread aThread;
    private static Loopy aLoop;

    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        startUpdate();
        stopUpdate();
        startUpdate();

    }

    public static void startUpdate() {

        aLoop = new Loopy();
        aThread = new Thread(aLoop);

        aThread.start();

    }

    public static void stopUpdate() {

        if (aThread != null) {
            aLoop.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

with runnable code that looks like:

```
public class Loopy implements Runnable {

    private static String status = "R";       // Run

    public void run() {

        while (status.equals("R")) {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
        status = "F";                         // End Run
    }
}
```

Calling startUpdate works the first time.

StopUpdate works as planned.

Calling startUpdate the second time results in no work being done as status is still equal to "F" from the stop, even though I am starting a new instance of Loopy which (to me) should have the default value of "R".

Is the status persisting across instances, or have I made an error I haven't spotted yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have overused `static`.

In your `Loopy` class the `String status` is `static` and is therefore shared across *all `Loopy` instances*.

You should make `status` an instance variable by removing the `static`.

Another note is that `status` should also be `volatile` as it's state is changed by numerous threads without synchronization.

I would also suggest that maybe you should make all the variables/methods in `Test` instance too (except `main`) as it's generally best to avoid `static` where possible:

```
public class Test {

    private Thread aThread;
    private Loopy aLoop;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Test test = new Test();
        test.startUpdate();
        test.stopUpdate();
        test.startUpdate();

    }

    public void startUpdate() {
        aLoop = new Loopy();
        aThread = new Thread(aLoop);
        aThread.start();
    }

    public void stopUpdate() {
        if (aThread != null) {
            aLoop.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about volatile, but I assume that as I am only intending there to be one thread running at once, it won't be necessary?

Comment: I meant that status is only updated by one process, not multiple simultaneous ones. Or am I missing something again!?

Comment: @shakeshuck you have your `main` `Thread` where the application starts and your `work` `Thread`. Your `work` `Thread` reads `status` and your `main` `Thread` writes `status`.

Comment: I found question 106591 which specifically touches on usage of volatile in this context. Spot on! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think status shoud not be static